# Osculating sphere at point of maximal curvature lies to one side

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, mg.metric-geometry, riemannian-geometry

I'm looking for the higher dimensional version of [this post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/409512/osculating-circle), which says that given a curve $\gamma \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$, the osculating circle will lie to one side of the curve at points of maximal curvature.

Formally, I am wondering if the following is known/proved: Let $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ a bounded, connected open set with $\partial \Omega = \Sigma^{n-1} \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ a smooth closed, orientable manifold. Does there exist a point $p$ such that the osculating sphere $S_{p, H(p)}$ lies entirely inside $\overline{\Omega}$ or entirely inside $\overline{\mathbb{R}^n \backslash \Omega}$? Intuitively, one could apply the maximum principle to the osculating sphere at a point which maximizes $|H_{\Sigma}(p)|$, though the details are unclear to me.

Comment: It's not clear that there exists an osculating *sphere* in general, even for a smooth surface embedded in 3-space, because its principal curvatures will in general be unequal. (There will exist, however, an osculating *quadric surface*.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As pointed out in the comment by Daniel Asimov, the osculating sphere is undefined (or may not exist).

But, one may ask about the size of the maximal ball surrounded by $\Sigma$ in terms of its principal curvatures --- this is the closest relative of your 1-dimensional question.

This question was considered in a sequence of papers by Vladimir Lagunov and Abram Fet;
they constructed examples of surfaces with principal curvatures at most 1 that do not surround a ball of radius 1.
You may check 11C in our book [What is differential geometry...](https://arxiv.org/abs/2012.11814v5) + you may check an [this video](https://youtu.be/88woMfyHrqc?si=tzkA1qXVU3X3RB6b) by Sergio Zamora.
Plus, here is artwork Ana Cristina Cháliz Cáliz from our book that illustrates one such example; this is the so-called Lagunov's fishbowl.

[image: Lagunov's fishbowl]

Comment: As depicted in the above drawing, Lagunov's fishbowl appears closely related to the contractible 2-complex known as the "house with two rooms" discovered by R.H. Bing.

Comment: @DanielAsimov sure, this example is homeomorphic to surface of genus 2; an analogous example for sphere is thickening of Bing's house; it seems that Lagunov reinvented this example in his paper.